# unable to assign value in the dropdownlist in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

im editing one gridview. while clicking edit im redirecting to one page and binding all the fields. but unble to bind month dropdown . i want to bind april month in dropdown but not binding

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLMonth" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem>Month</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="February" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="March" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="April" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="May" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="June" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="July" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="August" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="September" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="October" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="November" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="December" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
```

code behind

```
string DDLMonthstr = date.Month.ToString();//4
DDLMonth.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(DDLMonthstr);
```

Comment: Have you tried DDLMonth.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(DDLMonthstr);?

Comment: its working with selectedvalue but not working with selecteditem.value. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already selected item and need to clear selection using [ListControl.ClearSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection(v=vs.110).aspx) before making new selection through code.

```
string DDLMonthstr = date.Month.ToString();//4
DDLMonth.ClearSelection();
DDLMonth.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(DDLMonthstr);
```

Also check if you are getting any exception by using try-catch block if you do not already have, this could help in fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DDLMonth.Items.FindByValue(string val).Selected = true;
```